# Joining multiple threads in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am trying to write a C program that accepts a number `n` and computes the sum of cubic first `n` integers. The program also accepts the number of threads `p` that the user wants to compute the partial sums with. These partial sums are stored in an array `s` and then they will be summed up to the total sum. The input form is `n p`.

The program worked fine when I join the threads once they are created. However, when I join them in another loop after creating them, things don't go as intended as in the sample run.

I want to understand what is happening and how to overcome the problem.

This is the program::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long sum = 0, s[3000]={0}, p,n;
struct args{
    int i;
    long long lower;
    long long upper;
};

void* sum_runner(void* input){
    long long lower = ((struct args*)input)->lower;
    long long upper = ((struct args*)input)->upper;
    int i = ((struct args*)input)->i;

    for (long long j=lower; j<upper; ++j){
        s[i] += j*j*j;
    } 
    if (upper == n){
        s[i] += upper*upper*upper;
    }

    //pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    if (argc < 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: usage: a <p> <n>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (atoi(argv[1]) <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "n should be positive\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (atoi(argv[2]) <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "p should be positive\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (atoi(argv[2]) > 3000){
        fprintf(stderr, "number of threads should be less than 3000!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    p = atoi(argv[2]);
    n = atoll(argv[1]);

    if (n < p){
        fprintf(stderr, "the number of threads should be greater than the total number of numbers you want to sum\n");
        return -1;
    }


    pthread_t tids[p];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    struct args *aarg = (struct args *) malloc(sizeof(struct args));


    for (int k=0; k < p; ++k){
        aarg->i = k;
        aarg->lower = k * (n/p);

        aarg->upper = (k+1)*(n/p);
        if (aarg->upper == n - n%p){
            aarg->upper = n;
        }

        printf("k: %d, lower: %d, upper: %d\n", k, k * (n/p), aarg->upper);

        pthread_create(&tids[k], NULL, sum_runner, (void*) aarg);
        //pthread_join(tids[k], NULL);

    }

    for (int i=0; i < p; ++i){
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }
    long long totSum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < p; ++i){
        printf("sum on thread %d = %lld\n",i+1, s[i]);
        totSum += s[i];
    }

    printf("sum = %lld\n", totSum);
    //pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

[image: This is the sample run]

Comment: You're passing the address of the **same** `aarg` to **every** thread, and then changing the values in that structure while the child threads are running. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: Hmm, with `printf("k: %d, lower: %d, upper: %d\n", k, k * (n / p), aarg->upper);` I get "warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'long long int' [-Wformat=]".  Recommend enabling all warnings.

Comment: @AndrewHenle What I know so far is that I am creating only one thread each time I enter the for loop. And before each thread creation, I change the `aarg` value and pass it again with the new values to the new thread. Please correct me if I'm wrong because I am still grasping multithreading programming.

Comment: Move the malloc inside the loop so that each thread gets its own aarg.  Free the aarg just before the thread exits.